# How to apply:$\sum\limits^n_{k=1}f(k)=\sum\limits^n_{k=1}f(n+1-k)$

Tags: summation, applications

While reading a solution, I found this :$$\sum\limits^n_{k=1}f(k)=\sum\limits^n_{k=1}f(n+1-k)$$
I found it intriguing. What is the application of this? Because at the first look, it looks like it makes things more complicated.
At the first look it looked like the property of integrals that $\int^b_af(x)dx=\int^b_af(a+b-x)dx$. Is there really any resemblance?

**My attempt at proof:** We can write the LHS as: $$f(1)+f(2)+\dots+f(n)$$
And we can write the RHS as: $$f(n)+f(n-1)+...+f(1)$$ Thus LHS=RHS.

Comment: In sums with binomial coefficients it might not be so easy to see the symmetry so this could be useful, e.g. that $\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose n+1-k} = 2^n-1$ is not totally obvious (to me) at first glance.

Comment: In this example, is $n \choose n+1-k$ a function purely made of $k$?

Comment: Who said it has to be purely made out of $k$? I you want you can think of $n$ as just a fixed number then it's just a function of $k$.

Comment: Ohk. Hmm. Thanks. 0_o.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you stumble upon something that looks like your RHS, i.e. $\sum_{k=1}^n f(n+1-k)$, at some point during your research/homework. Then apply the formula to it and you get that it equals $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)$. Thus you made your life easier (according to yourself, the latter expression looks less complicated than what you first stumbled upon)

PS: your proof is, of course, correct, but depending on your level it does not have the sufficient level of stringency. Why can you switch the order of sums? Why is that expression with the $\Sigma$ on the RHS equal to the expression with the dots, etc.

Comment: Ahh yes! Hehe. Can you give a simple example?

Comment: Say you already know that $\sum_{j=1}^n j=(n+1)n/2$. What is $\sum_{j=1}^n(n+1-j)$? Well, the same

Comment: Can you elaborate on "sufficient level of stringency"? I have seen such considerations being useful only if we are dealing with an infinite sum.

Comment: Why? Why can't I switch the order of terms? Obviously commutativity. And for the dots part because the sum is till $n$, so $n+1-k$ will equal $1$ at $k=n$.

Comment: Yes, obviously commutativity. But I wasn't the one asking the question. Your first semester math professor (mine at least) would want to hear that argument. And for the sum, yes, but I don't know how you introduced (if at all) expressions with dots. But anyway: I never claimed there is mathematical insight in all this.

Comment: Then you tell me what is the method to introduce "expressions with dots". Does it really require a proof.?

Comment: No, it doesn't really. It is just that dots are not something that your teachers usually want to see because they introduce some level of vagueness. For example, is $2*1+...+2*3$ equal to 12 or 20?

Comment: Cannot see why it would be $30$. And your expression is also unclear. You should put brackets. I don't think putting dots in $f(1)+\cdots+f(n)$ makes it unclear or vague.

Comment: Yes, but it is a reason to just avoid dots in general. Because when you are doing research and write down the expression I wrote down above, you will get into trouble when complexity adds up. The reason is that when you are juggling with real life expression you won't have f-of-k's but expressions that contain multiple different numbers and variables and indices. And then dots are very dangerous/unclear.